# When I use billing for cafe bazaar in my app, this message " there is no product "

Tags: react-native, in-app-billing

I used a library to pay cafe bazaar for the app
And I did all the settings that it, But my app encountered an error
When I use this message" there is no product"
my code:

```
CafeBazaar.open()
        .then(() => CafeBazaar.purchase('my_sku_in_cafe_bazaar', '', 1840))
        .then((details) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(details));
            return CafeBazaar.close()
        })
        .catch((err) =>{
            if(err.code==="E_SETUP_DISCONNECT"){
                alert("cafeBazaar Not install, please install it and so try again");
            }else{
                alert(JSON.stringify(err))
            }
        } );
```

You can see for better

picture of mycode+result in my app
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem
The package project should be the name of the package in the cafe bazaar(like: com.XXX.XXXXXXX)

I tested the sample project

like it :)